# Union and Intersection in PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have an array of objects of the following structure:

```
structure Disk
{
  int UID;
  String Computer;
}
```

A computer may have a bunch of shared disks, and a disk may be shared among computers.

I want to find out all the disks common to all the computers. For example, I have computer A, B, and C; Disks 1, 2, and 3.
The disk array is {1,A}, {1,B}, {2,A},{2,B},{2,C},{3,A}.
The result that I want should be the disk 2, because it appears on A, B, and C.

Is there a effective way to achieve this?

With multiple foreach loops it's achievable, but definitely I want a better way. I'm thinking about operations like intersection, but didn't find this in PowerShell.

Comment: I would recommend to change the title to "Union, Intersection and Difference / Set Subtraction in PowerShell". So we'll have all set operations in one place.

Comment: Based on the question and suggestions here, I have created a PowerShell function to do Union, Intersection and Minus for objects. Check it out: https://sqljana.wordpress.com/2015/09/23/perform-set-operations-union-intersection-minus-complement-using-powershell/

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Assuming `$arr` is the array, you can do like this:

```
$computers = $arr | select -expand computer -unique
$arr | group uid | ?{$_.count -eq $computers.count} | select name
```

---

In general, I would approach union and intersection in Powershell like this:

```
$a = (1,2,3,4)
$b = (1,3,4,5)
$a + $b | select -uniq    #union
$a | ?{$b -contains $_}   #intersection
```

But for what you are asking, the above solution works well and not really about union and intersection in the standard definition of the terms.

Update:

I have written [pslinq](https://github.com/manojlds/pslinq) which provides `Union-List` and `Intersect-List` that help to achieve set union and intersection with Powershell.

Comment: Cool stuff, how would these oneliners work with keyed collections like Hashtables?

Comment: Great post -- there should be a standard library for arrays that provides functionality like that. lodash for powershell..

Comment: for completeness you can get the set difference between $a and $b using
$a | ?{$b -notcontains $_}   #difference

Comment: is anyone able to provide me a link to technet that shows me definition and/or examples of the ?{...} structure

Comment: ? is an alias to Where-Object, so ? {} --> Where-Object -FilterScript {...}

Answer (score 28):

You can also do

```
$a = (1,2,3,4)
$b = (1,3,4,5)
Compare-Object $a $b -PassThru -IncludeEqual                   # union
Compare-Object $a $b -PassThru -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent # intersection
```

Doesn't work if `$a` is null though.

Comment: Could add $null to the array. $a = 1,2,3,4,$null

Answer (score 15):

For set subtraction (a - b):

`$a | ?{-not ($b -contains $_)}`

Comment: There is also -notcontains.

Comment: Narthan save people time and write it out next time :) ``$a | ?{$b -notcontains $_}``

Answer (score 13):

While this won't work in the earliest versions, in more recent versions you can just call the .NET LINQ extension functions directly, e.g.

```
[system.linq.enumerable]::union([object[]](1,2,3),[object[]](2,3,4))
```

(Without the cast to some enumerable type, PowerShell throws a "cannot find overload" error.)

This definitely works in PowerShell V4 and V5 and definitely doesn't in V2.  I don't have a system at hand with V3.

Answer (score 2):

I realised no-one answered your specific example of computers a, b, c, with disks numbered 1, 2, 3 attached.
Code and output given for Intersection, Union and Set difference across the three sets

#### Code

```
$a = @(1, 2, 3)
$b = @(1, 2)
$c = @(2)

'Intersection $a ⋂ $b ⋂ $c'
$a | Where-Object {$_ -In $b} | Where-Object {$_ -In $c}

'Union $a ⋃ $b ⋃ $c'
$a + $b + $c | Select-Object -Unique

'Set difference $a - $b - $c (items in $a but not $b or $c)'
$a | Where-Object {$_ -NotIn $b} | Where-Object {$_ -NotIn $c}
```

#### Output

```
Intersection $a ⋂ $b ⋂ $c
2
Union $a ⋃ $b ⋃ $c
1
2
3
Set difference $a - $b - $c (items in $a but not $b or $c)
3
```

Comment: Marvellous post.. Just what I was after..