# How to check duplicate file name using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to check if I have .xml file first, if I have .xml file, the I have to check the .xml file existed, duplicated or not. 
For the example, I have those 3 file:
ABC_123.xml
ABC_456.PRO
ABC_123.PRO

From those file, it means I have `.xml` file `(ABC_123.xml)`, then `.xml` file is duplicted with this file `ABC_123.PRO`. Then I have to c`ontinue to other process`.

I tried this, but it still return the result I have duplicate file, even I change the file name of .xml to `DEF_123.xml` or other name with .xml extension.

```
for(;;)
{
$Path = "D:\SERVICE"
if(Test-Path -Path "$Path\*.xml")
{
    Write-Host "XML exist"
    $XML_File = Get-ChildItem -Name "$Path\*.xml"
    $PRO_File = Get-ChildItem -Name "$Path\*.PRO"
    if($XML_File.BaseName -eq $PRO_File.BaseName)
    {
        Write-Host "Duplicated"
        Write-Host "Continue other process
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "Not duplicate, process the xml file"

    }

}
else{
    Write-Host "XML not exist"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script doesn't work, because

```
$XML_File = Get-ChildItem -Name "$Path\*.xml"
$PRO_File = Get-ChildItem -Name "$Path\*.PRO"
if($XML_File.BaseName -eq $PRO_File.BaseName)
```

doesn't do what is intended. `Get-ChildItem` returns an array of `FileInfo` objects if there is more than one file with matching extension. An array doesn't have `BaseName`, so if you would use `Set-StrictMode -Version 'latest'`, you'd get an error about non-existing property.

As for a solution, [leverage set-based](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8609204) logic. Like so,

```
# Assume that these test files exist
data.xml
data2.pro
data2.xml
data3.xml

# Two empty arrays, populate each with basenames and see results
$xbase = @()
$obase = @()
@(gci * -include *.xml) | % { $xbase += $_.basename }
$xbase
data
data2
data3

@(gci * -exclude *.xml) | % { $obase += $_.basename }
$obase
data2
```

Now there are two arrays that contain basenames for XML files and non-XML files. To create a new collection of files that don't have a non-XML counterpart, compare the collections like so,

```
$onlyXML = Compare-Object $xbase $obase -PassThru
$onlyXML
data
data3
```

Now the `$onlyXML` collection contains basenames for files that do not have a counterpart in the non-XML collection. Processing it is easy enough, just remember to add `.xml` to access the actual file.

```
$onlyXML | % {
    $x = gci "$_.xml" # For example, get a FileInfo about XML doc
    # TODO: do stuff with $x
}
```